# Parser AST - Advantage of Binary Expression vs Function

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I've written a parser for a simple in house SQL style language. It's a typical recursive descent parser.

Naturally, we have expressions, and two of the possible forms of expressions I model are `BinaryExpression` and `FunctionExpression`. My question is, since a binary expression can be modelled as a function with two arguments, is there any advantage in keeping the distinction?

Perhaps function invocation is not normally modelled as an expression but as a statement, but here all my functions must produce a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you choose to model your language is really up to you; it completely depends on how you intend to use the AST you construct.

Certainly there is no fundamental difference between evaluation of a binary operator and evaluation of a function with two arguments. On the other hand, there is a significant difference in the presentation (in most languages). Certain operators have very well understood properties which can be of use during static analysis, such as finding optimisations.

So both styles are certainly valid, and you will have to make the choice based on your knowledge of the intended use(s) of the AST.